# too many renders react hooks, useEffect, map

Tags: firebase, react-hooks, use-effect

hey guys I'm trying to add to sum a simple product price for each iteration and notice its runs too manytimes. in the use effect I have to listen to the UserCart. can't do it with an empty array/[userCart].
also I get the following error in more components which i couldnt fix for the same reason with the last argument in the useEffect:

update: I did divide the useEffect as suggusted but it with [userCart ] it enter infinite loop

the code:

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    import firebase from 'firebase';
    import { useAuth, useStoreUpdate } from '../contexts/FirebaseContext';
    
        export default function Cart() {
            const [userMail, setUserMail] = useState(undefined)
            const [userCart, setUserCart] = useState(undefined)
            const [totalAmmout, setTotalAmmout] = useState(0)
            const user = useAuth()
            const userDoc = firebase.firestore().collection("cart").doc(userMail)
            const updateStore = useStoreUpdate()
        
            const updateCart = () => {
                userDoc.get().then((doc) => {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        let cart = doc.data()
                        setUserCart(cart)
                    }
                })
            }
        
            async function removeFromCart(itemId, name, url, price, category, type, description) {
                const cartItem = { itemId, name, url, price, category, type, description }
                await userDoc.update({
                    item: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(cartItem)
                })
                await updateCart()
                await updateStore()
            }
        
            useEffect(() => {
                if (user.currentUser) {
                    setUserMail(user.currentUser.email)
                    updateCart()
                    updateStore()
        
                }
            },userCart)
        
            if (!userCart) return <h1>hold</h1>
            let total = 0
            return (
                <main className="main-cart">
                    <div className="container">
                        {userCart.item && userCart.item.length >= 1 && userCart.item.map((item, i, arr) => {
                           
                            console.log(item);  //it runs more than 20 times
                            return (
                                < div className="item-container" key={item.itemId} >
                                    <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                                    <p>{item.price}</p>
                                    <img height="150px" width="150px" src={item.url} alt="" />
                                    <button onClick={async () => {
                                        await removeFromCart(item.itemId, item.name, item.url, item.price, item.category, item.type, item.description)
                                    }}>X</button>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })}
        
                    </div>
                    <div className="fixed-bottom-link">
                        <button>finish purchase</button>
                    </div>
                </main >
            )
        }
```

edit :

I found the major component, but still couldnt make it work
the 2nd useEffect [userCart] wont run, it works only when not in the array, but it enter a loop:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { auth } from '../firebase/firebase';
import firebase from '../firebase/firebase';

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext()
const StoreContext = React.createContext()
const StoreContextUpdate = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(FirebaseContext)
}
export function useStore() {
    return useContext(StoreContext)
}

export function useStoreUpdate() {
    return useContext(StoreContextUpdate)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [userMail, setUserMail] = useState(undefined)
    const [userCart, setUserCart] = useState(undefined)
    const userDoc = firebase.firestore().collection("cart").doc(userMail)

    const updateCart = () => {
        userDoc.get().then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                let cart = doc.data()
                setUserCart(cart)
            }
        })
    }


    function signup(email, password) {
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }

    function login(email, pasword) {
        return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pasword)
    }

    function logout() {
        return auth.signOut()
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
            await setCurrentUser(user)
            
            await setLoading(false)
        })
        return unsubscribe
    }, [userCart])

    useEffect(()=>{
        async function refreshCart(){
             await setUserMail(currentUser.email);
             await updateCart()   
         }
        if (currentUser && currentUser.email) {
               refreshCart()
           
        }
        return
    },[userCart])



    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup,
        login,
        logout
    }
    return (
        <FirebaseContext.Provider value={value}>
            <StoreContext.Provider value={userCart && userCart.item}>
                <StoreContextUpdate.Provider value={updateCart}>
                    {!loading && children}
                </StoreContextUpdate.Provider>
            </StoreContext.Provider>
        </FirebaseContext.Provider>
    )
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.currentUser) {
      setUserMail(user.currentUser.email);
      updateCart();
      updateStore();
    }
  }, [userCart]); //<-- userCart needs to be inside array
```

and the reason for too many rerenders is you're calling `updateCart` function when the `userCart` changes and then `userCart` change will cause the call of `updateCart` again and this loop will repeat itself until you're out of memory

I think adding another `useEffect` might help you

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.currentUser) {
      setUserMail(user.currentUser.email);
      updateStore();
    }
  }, [userCart]); //<-- userCart needs to be inside array

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.currentUser) {
      updateCart();
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Ty for the comment. Inside the array it enters a loop.

Comment: @YanivCode I know, I was mentioning that it's not correct to pass a variable as the second input of `useEffect` instead of an array

Comment: was a nice try adding another useEffect but it didnt do the trick /: 
it just doesn't load the userCart. no errors to display

Comment: after divide the useEffect it runs the render from 20 times to 4 time only. very greatful

Comment: @YanivCode glad I could help bro :), but by accepting the answer I mean clicking on the tick button (✔) ;)

Comment: need 15 reputation to do that /:

Comment: @YanivCode I think you could try it now :)